# What regular expression should I use to allow Runnable Snippet tags through NoScript Anti-XSS Protection?

Tags: firefox, noscript

I am running NoScript in Firefox and every time I try to use a Runnable Snippet, NoScript asks me whether I want to allow the potential cross site script to execute.  I can provide a regular expression to bypass the notification, but I want to make sure that it is as targeted as possible so that *actual* XSS attacks don't get through (not that Stack Exchange would ever have one of those).

I tried:

```
^https?://stackexchange\.com/questions/.*$
```

But I still get the exception.  Should I be targeting `http://stacksnippets.net` instead?

I also tried:

```
^https?://stacksnippets\.net.*$
```

Which works, but is that the most targeted RegEx I can make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a bit paranoid, but I would add the requirement that after the `.net` no letter or dot is allowed for the first character. If there is a top-level domain `.netmal` or `.net.au` (like there is `.com.au`), someone could go out and register `stacksnippets.netmal`/`stacksnippets.net.au` and run their malware there.

So something like:

```
^https?://stacksnippets\.net([/?].*)?$
```

This would require a `/` or `?` right after the base url, ensuring that the domain really is stacksnippets.net and nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, I like that a lot better than what I originally had.  Didn't even think to consider newer top-level domains.